# Rubocop: Is it possible to tell Rubocop to return zero as exit code when only warnings are found?

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci, rubocop

**Question**

Is it possible to tell Rubocop to return `0` as exit code when only warnings are found?

**Prerequisites**

1. I am using the following command to run Rubocop on Travis CI:

   ```sh
   bundle exec rubocop
   ```
2. I have a cop which is configured as a warning in `rubocop.yml`:

   ```yaml
   Style/Documentation:
     Severity: warning
   ```

**Problem**

Travis CI treats a command as a successful one only if its exit code is equal to `0`.

Rubocop returns `0` as exit code when it finds no offences,

but when it finds at least one offence,

it returns `1` as exit code, no matter whether this offence is an error or a warning.

As a result, Travis CI builds are failed when only warnings are found by Rubocop.

Therefore, is it possible to tell Rubocop to return `0` as exit code when only warnings are found?

Thanks in advance.

**Notes**

- Please, do NOT suggest to disable cops.
- I am using the following approach to check exit codes:

  ```sh
  $ bundle exec rubocop
  // ...
  14 files inspected, 8 offenses detected

  $ echo "$?"
  1
  ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `--fail-level` flag with the appropriate `severity` level:

```
rubocop --fail-level error
```

You can read more about this flag in the [Rubocop Docs for command line flags](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.88/usage/basic_usage.html#command-line-flags) and the `severity` level in the [Rubocop Docs for Generic configuration parameters](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.88/configuration.html#severity).

Given `foo.rb`:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo; end
```

And `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Severity: warning
```

Run Rubocop with the appropriate flags:

```
rubocop --fail-level error
```

And get the following output:

```
Inspecting 1 file
W

Offenses:

foo.rb:1:1: W: Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment: Missing frozen string literal comment.
class Foo
^
```

And then get the exit code:

```
echo $?
0
```

Verify it's working as expected by modifying your `.rubocop.yml` to use `error` rather than `warning`:

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Severity: error
```

Run it again and get the output:

```
rubocop --fail-level error
Inspecting 1 file
E

Offenses:

foo.rb:1:1: E: Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment: Missing frozen string literal comment.
class Foo
^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

And get the exit code:

```
echo $?
1
```